# Gimp clipping mask doesn't work any longer

Tags: gimp, images, mask, scale

Up until recently I was able to scale images in Gimp without any problem, but I have may touched something and now everything that goes beyond the original size boundary gets cropped. I have made sure the option "Clipping>Adjust" is selected, and have tried the "Reset to default values" to no avail.

Does anybody know what is going on/ what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

To scale images use  `Image>Scale image`. From your description you seem to be scaling the layers using the Scale tool instead. If you keep using that tool, use `Image>Fit canvas to layers` when the new layer is bigger than the image canvas.